# I keep Getting an out of bounds error

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone help me with the array size? the reverse array keeps getting out of bounds and i can't figure out how to fix it. The purpose of the program is to have the user enter a sentence, the the program will find out how many palindromes are present, and what they are

```
package palindrome;

import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

class Palindrome2
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
  //String[] reverse; //Reverse word
  String[] words;
  int count = 0;
  String palindromes[];

  //User Input
  String original = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Words that are the same "
          + "forwards and backwards are called palindromes.\n"
          + "This program determines if a word is a palindrome.\n\n"
          + "Enter a word: ");

  //Length of the Input
  int length = original.length();


  //Spliting the original into an Array

  words = original.split("\\s");



  //Reversing the User's Input
  String[] reverse = new String[words.length];


  for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++){

      int wordLength = words[j].length();

      for ( int i = wordLength - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
       reverse[i] = reverse[i] + original.charAt(i);
   }
  }

  //Determining if it is a Palindrome and Output 


  for (int l = 0; l < words.length; l++){

      if (original.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse[l])) {

       count = count + 1;

       palindromes = new String[count];
       palindromes[l] = reverse[l];


   }
  else {

  }
   }

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + count + " Palindromes"
        + " in this sentence");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The palindromes are:\n"+ palindromes);
```

}

}

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? And what line causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you mean

```
reverse[j] = reverse[j] + original.charAt(i);
```

Comment: I changed it to that and it got rid of the out of bounds error! Thanks! however, there are stil other problems :\